# WordPress Contact Form 7 - validation responses are empty and not displaying

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, response, contact-form-7

I have a problem with WordPress site using Contact Form 7 plugin. 
The response boxes, that normally inform user after clicking 'submit' button with alerts, if the form was filled incorrectly or with green box information, if everything went fine and the mail was sent.

the empty response div (with display: none; unchanged after submit):

```
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
```

Here's what I've got so far tested:

- No other plugins are interfering
- it's not theme problem
- jquery core and jquery migrate was updated to 3.1.1
- WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY does not throw any errors in PHP
- CF7 is in version 4.9, also tested 4.7 and the newest 5.0.4 - with same result

Any help would be appreciated, I'm running out of ideas to solve this looks-like-easy-to-fix bug..

edit: added the response div.

Comment: Can you share a link to the site so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Not really, it's still in development on my local server, what details do you need?

Comment: I was going to check to see if any JavaScript errors were being thrown.  Also: have you checked your server error log?  What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: PHP ver 7, no JS errors in console.

Comment: Unfortunately without being able to access and test the form myself to see why it's not updating as expected, I can't really help any more than these general questions.  Good luck!  If you want more help, put the site up somewhere I can reach it and I'll be glad to take a look.